# Modifying query using Spark Catalyst Logical Plan

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to add/replace existing column expression in 
DataFrame API/SQL using extension point.

Ex: assume we inject resolution rule which could check the project
node from the plan and on checking for column "name", replace it
with upper(name) for instance.

Is such a thing possible using Extension Points. The examples which i have 
found are mostly simple, which do not manipulate the input expressions  in the manner i need.

Kindly let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Why do you want to convert project attribute name to upper case? Can you tell the use case?

Comment: @prakharjain - My use case is to modify query based on some conditions . Its not possible to change the client program. So exploring catalyst right now. Upper  case is just an example. It could be anything.

Comment: @BhanupalSinghRathore Please check the answer below and see if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Lets take an example. Suppose we want to write a rule which checks for Project operator and if the project is for some particular column (say 'column2'), then it multiply it by 2.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.Rule
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object DoubleColumn2OptimizationRule extends Rule[LogicalPlan] {
    def apply(plan: LogicalPlan): LogicalPlan = plan transform {
        case p: Project =>
          if (p.projectList.filter(_.name == "column2").size >= 1) {
              val newList = p.projectList.map { case x =>
                if (x.name == "column2") {
                  Alias(Multiply(Literal(2, IntegerType), x), "column2_doubled")()
                } else {
                  x
                }
              }
              p.copy(projectList = newList)
          } else {
              p
          }
    }
}
```

say we have a table "table1" which has two columns - column1, column2.

Without this rule -

```
> spark.sql("select column2 from table1 limit 10").collect()
Array([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
```

with this rule -

```
> spark.experimental.extraOptimizations =  Seq(DoubleColumn2OptimizationRule)
> spark.sql("select column2 from table1 limit 10").collect()
Array([2], [4], [6], [8], [10], [12], [14], [16], [18], [20])
```

Also you can call explain on DataFrame to check the plan -

```
> spark.sql("select column2 from table1 limit 10").explain
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 10
+- *(1) LocalLimit 10
   +- *(1) Project [(2 * column2#213) AS column2_doubled#214]
      +- HiveTableScan [column2#213], HiveTableRelation `default`.`table1`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [column1#212, column2#213]
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. I was working with UDFs on cols rather than literal values. Using AttributeExpression was the problem in my case. However i did look at  the example and wrapped my code in alias and it works fine.